# Need help proving that a function is continuous without knowing what the function is explicitly

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and there exists $c \geq 0$ with $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c |x-y|$, for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.  Show that $f$ is continuous.

It doesn't like there is enough information to prove it is continuous. I'm not sure how to approach the problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

If $c = 0$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ for all $x,y$, so $f$ is constant, hence continuous. So we may assume $c > 0$.

Take any $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \epsilon / c$. Then, for any $x,y$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$, we have 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c|x-y| < c\delta = c\frac{\epsilon}{c} = \epsilon$$
which shows that $f$ is continuous, in fact uniformly continuous since $\delta$ does not depend on $x$ or $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually functions satisfying the above inequality are called Lipchitz continuous and note that Lipchitz continuity is stronger than  uniform continuity.For instance consider following examples on $R$

- $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$
- $g(x) = |x|\sin{\frac{1}{|x|}}$, where $f(0) = 0$